# protractor map panning IE 11 and edge is failing

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor. I am using Jasmine framework. I have a map and I am getting it as `elm1 = element(by.id("mapId"));`. I want to pan the map to particular point.

I am using following code. 
`browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elm1, { x: 1300, y: 370 }).perform();`

It is failing in IE11 and edge. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Can you add more debug details .. like .. are you seeing any error stack? and are you seeing an element locator errors?